# Android Google Translate API Permission Denied

Tags: android, google-api, google-translate

I've been trying to get the Google Translate API working. I have read and re-read a number of posts, as well as the Google Cloud authentication guide (http://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-java) but still must be missing something.
As per the guide and following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379897/missing-a-valid-api-key-about-google-translation-api-client-issue , I created a Service Account called ABCD and made myself project owner in the GCP Console. I downloaded the JSON file and placed it in a folder called JSON. I then created a system environment variable manually-GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with a value of C:\Users\aaa\AndroidStudioProjects\JSON.

When I look at the IAM & admin page in the GCP console, it shows my service account, with an id of ABCD@helpful-monitorxxxxxxxxx.com as well as the Key Id.

Here is my MainActivity class as well as an Aync task class to do the translation.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Trans translate = new Trans();
        String text = ("Hello world");
        String res = translate.execute(text).toString();
    }
}


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translation;

public class Transl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String text = "Hello friend"; //text to translate
        Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        Translation translation =
                translate.translate(
                        text,
                        Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
                        Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("fr"));
        return translation.getTranslatedText();Fatal Exception 
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", result);
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get a Fatal RunTime exception-

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
    {
        "code" : 403,
        "errors" : [ {
            "domain" : "global",
            "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
            "reason" : "forbidden"
        } ],
        "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
```

I can't really find any way to debug it. Do I need to do something further to enable the account/API key? Is there code missing?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Did you include the whole jsonPath when you create the system environment variable- GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS? (not only the folder where the file is, but the whole path, something like C:\Users\aaa\AndroidStudioProjects\JSON\[xxxxxxxxxxx.json] ).  You can also [provide service account credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually).

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting to this address with the key at the end?

https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/?key=>http encoded API key here<

If so, are you using an actual API key?

If not, when you look at the "Google Cloud Platform" in the Console for your app, click on the little key on the left side to take you the "Credentials" page.

Then if you don't see "API keys" , then click on "Create credentials" blue button, and select "API Key"

Then use this as your key in your URL address I mentioned above to POST to.